# jQuery .on() click function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, calendar

I got a little calendar with the [jQuery UI Datepicker plugin](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/).

---

When I click a date, a function should fire (but doesn't).
First I tried to use this code:

```
$('.ui-datepicker-calendar td').click(function(){
  console.log("Test");
});
```

That only fires once tho, since the calendar is dynamically added.
So I changed it to that:

```
$(document).on('click', '.ui-datepicker-calendar td', function(){
  console.log("Test");
});
```

But that doesn't work at all, what doesn't make sense to me.
Here you got a snippet:

```js
$('#calendar').datepicker({
  inline: true,
  firstDay: 1,
  showOtherMonths: true,
  dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat']
});

$(document).on('click', '.ui-datepicker-calendar td', function(){
  console.log("Test");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="calendar"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
 $('#calendar').datepicker({
     inline: true,
     firstDay: 1,
     showOtherMonths: true,
     dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
     onSelect: function(date) {
        alert(date);
     },
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="calendar"></div>
```

There is a function for ***datepicker*** `onSelect` it will work on every click on a date. no need to bind any extra click event.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's only firing once tho.

Comment: @TobiasGlaus check the fiddle

Comment: Thanks alot, that's working! I came across `onSelect` already, but it was poorly described on the API documentation, so I didn't use it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @TobiasGlaus Glad you sort it out :)